# Why is video bigger than the sum of its frames

Tags: avconv

I tried making a video out of 1000 PNG files with total size 25.3MB.
When I used the commands I found for lossless video-encoding like
`avconv -i Images%04d.png -c:v huffyuv  output.avi`
my videos turned out to have 630MB. 
How is that possible, and how can I avoid that?

Comment: PNG is pretty good at lossless image compression. So if you do "lossless video-encoding" chances are that the "lossless" part means that the images are not compressed at all, or with some method which is not as good as PNG. - I don't think there is something like "motion-PNG", so that the encoder will have to de-compress each image first to put it into the video; therefore, the final size of the video will most likely have nothing to do with the size of the PNG files.

Comment: @HannoBinder Sounds like you should make that an answer.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

huffyuv is a very inefficient compression. It applys no temporal or spacial compression at all. It simply just zips up each frame. PNG uses compression specifically tuned for images. You can use a something like lossless AVC. It will still be fairly large (maybe even still larger that the sum of its parts) but it will be MUCH smaller than 630MB.